# Changing the default login credentials to internet on my samsung phone

Tags: wi-fi

I bought a Samsung galaxy chat phone a few weeks back. I experienced difficulties downloading whatsapp at the workplace, where we have access to wifi. As a result, I enlisted assistance of a technician, who ended up using his credentials to login to wifi, and successfully downloaded whatsapp and few other apps into the phone.

Each time I have to login to wifi at work, the login screen comes with the technician's username and (the dots at the password window - for) his password. I have to delete these each time before typing-in my own, and it is rather inconvenient, even frustrating. How do I get rid of these default credentials of the technician and have mine (or blanks) instead?

Will greatly appreciate your assistance.
Thanks 
Silas

Comment: Am I assuming correctly you're talking about a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) here, and that "login screen" actually is a page shown in your web browser? If so, you might need to remove the stored credentials there (from the browser settings).

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning your Android version would have made it easier to provide specific instructions, but then it's pretty easy

Press or tap *Menu* button →*Settings*→*Wireless & Networks* → *Wi-Fi*

Long press your office *Wi-Fi* network → *Forget*

Go back to *Wi-Fi* settings page, your office network will show up (if it doesn't *Scan* for it). Enter your username and password and save. Subsequently, it will connect automatically and show your office network name instead of technician

Comment: The recommendation by beeshyams was spot-on and extremely useful. I was able to follow the suggestions, and instantaneously disabled  the default login credentials - very much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you and since it met your needs, you can "accept" it by clicking the tick mark next to answer. This would also show others that the answer has merit, when they search . You do not have enough reputation to upvote now, once you acquire 15 points, you can upvote any answer you like